# Regex:: 'pandas._libs.interval.Interval' object has no attribute 'replace'

Tags: python, regex, data-wrangling

I have data frame with a column

```
id       bins                  
1      (2, 3]        
2      (4, 5]       
3      (6, 7]        
4      (8, 9]       
5      (10, 11]
```

I am trying to get something like this.

```
    id       bins                  
    1      2 -  3        
    2      4 -  5       
    3      6 -  7        
    4      8 -  9       
    5      10 -  11
```

I am aiming to use regex to achieve this. I am afraid I am not that expert in regex. This is partly the solution I tried without any success.

```
   df['bins'].astype(str).str.replace(']', ' ')
   df['bins'].astype(str).str.replace(',', ' - ')
   df['bins'] = df['bins'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('[','').replace(']',''))
```

Any help will be appreciated!!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
df['bins'] = df['bins'].astype(str).str.replace(r'[][()]+', '', regex=True).str.replace(',', ' - ')
```

Note:

- `.replace(r'[][()]+', '', regex=True)` - removes one or more `]`, `[`, `(` and `)` chars
- `.str.replace(',', ' - ')` - replaces all commas with space+`-`+space.

Another way:

```py
df['bins'].astype(str).str.replace(r'\((\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+)]', r'\1 - \2', regex=True)
```

Here, `\((\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+)]` matches

- `\(` - a `(` char
- `(\d+)` - Group 1 (`\1`): one or more digits
- `\s*,\s*` - a comma enclosed with zero or more whitespaces
- `(\d+)` - Group 2 (`\2`): one or more digits
- `]` - a `]` char.

Pandas test:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'bins':['(2, 3]']})
>>> df['bins'].astype(str).str.replace(r'\((\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+)]', r'\1 - \2', regex=True)
0    2 - 3
Name: bins, dtype: object
>>> df['bins'].astype(str).str.replace(r'[][()]+', '', regex=True).str.replace(',', ' - ')
0    2 -  3
Name: bins, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it a bit differently with `re`. looking for numbers and joining them in one string :

```
df['bins'] = df['bins'].apply(lambda x: " - ".join(re.findall("(\d+)", x)))

df
   id     bins 
0   1    2 - 3
1   2    4 - 5
2   3    6 - 7
3   4    8 - 9 
4   5  10 - 11
```

Answer (score 0):

You did

```
   df['bins'].astype(str).str.replace(']', ' ')
   df['bins'].astype(str).str.replace(',', ' - ')
```

but `.str.replace` does not work inplace, you should assign what it returned back, otherwise no change will be done to your `pandas.DataFrame`, simple example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[100,200,300]})
df['col1'].astype(str).str.replace('100','1000')
print(df)  # there is still 100
df['col1'] = df['col1'].astype(str).str.replace('100','1000')
print(df)  # now there is 1000 rather than 100
```